# Am I doing it right conducting Mann–Whitney test in scipy?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, scipy

I have a group of users. I comapre their behaviour before and after certain event. 
Here are distributions of the metric before and after event.

[image]

Here are distrubutions `<quantile(.99)`

[image]

It seems like nothing had changed. Am I right?
I would like to check whether the metric has risen after an event.

I have trouble understanding `alternative` parameter of scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu. 
What should I use in this case: `None`,  `‘less’`, `‘two-sided’`, or `‘greater’`?

When I use `None` the change is significant, when I use `'greater'` p-value = 1.

Comment: You should not be [choosing your alternative by looking at your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data).

Comment: I think in most cases, a two-sided test is what people want.  Even when people think they're asking "Is this treatment better than the control?", they would also want to know if the treatment is worse than the control! ...It looks like the `none` option is deprecated, and,  to me, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Also note that with thousands of data points, the test is likely to be sensitive to small changes in the distribution of the two groups.  To make sense of your results you will likely need to look at the effect size in some way.  Also note, that if you have before-and-after data on the same subjects, that the Mann-Whitney test may not be the appropriate test.

Comment: @SalMangiafico thank you so much for your explanation! It is really helpful. What test would you use for before and after data?

Comment: If you can pair the observations --- that is, if you know user 1 had this score before and user 1 had this score after --- then you could use a Wilcoxon signed rank test.  If you don't have this kind of information, then you would use the Mann-Whitney.  But if you have the same users before and after, you should at least make note of this fact.

Comment: @SalMangiafico now I get it. So I could use Wilcoxon for all users or split users in half then use score before from one part and score after for the second part in Mann-Whitney. Right?

Comment: Either the MW or WSR test would have the same intent: to compare the before group to the after group.  The issue I was trying to get at is that the WM includes an assumption that the observations are independent.  If you have the same users before and after, then this assumption is violated.  But if you don't have data in a way that you can match the before and after score for each user, then there's not much you can do about it.  But in that case, you should alert your audience to this fact.

Comment: @SalMangiafico thank you!